# How to hide the FloatingActionButton that is part of the Activity in the Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, floating-action-button

In my 'HomeActivity', I have a `FloatingActionButton` and four `Fragments`. I want the `FloatingActionButton` to be shown only in the 'fragment1' and 'fragment2' make hide it in the 'fragment3' and 'fragment4'. I tried but it didn't work.

Following is what I have in the `xml` file of the 'HomeActivity'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hide_category"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I added the below code in the 'HomeActivity'

```
fun hideFabOne(){
    binding.fabOne.hide()
}
```

and below code in the `onCreateView` of the `fragment`s where I want to hide the FAB. But, it didn't work.

```
HomeActivity().hideFabOne()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are creating new instance of activity , try

```
(requireActivity() as HomeActivity).hideFabOne()
```

*Add for comment
You can modify the `hideFabOne()` something like

```
fun hideFabOne(){
    binding.fabOne.visiblity = if( binding.fabOne.isVisible ) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. But I have an issue with this and I have been trying to fix it but I couldn't fix it. How can I check whether the `binding.fabOne` is currently visible or not and if it's visible then hide it otherwise show. Can you help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: @Codist check latest

Comment: It's 'fragment1' which is being shown when the app launches and the button is visible by default and that is OK as I need the button to be shown in the 'fragment1'. When I navigate to 'fragment3', it's hidden and this is what I need. But, when I navigate back to 'fragment1' it's hidden as there is no function to show it. That's why I wanted to show/hide based on the current visibility. But for 'fragment1', when the app launches the visibility is 'VISIBLE' and when navigating back from 'fragment3' the visibility is 'INVISIBLE'. How to tackle this?

Comment: the easiest way would be registering observers to trigger change like [this example](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Naruto/blob/c4a3f5ae6cb75c64c12311b5d098a19ebc855cf7/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/naruto/ui/main/MainActivity.kt#L40) using to hide bottomNav , triggered by [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Naruto/blob/c4a3f5ae6cb75c64c12311b5d098a19ebc855cf7/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/naruto/ui/main/MainActivity.kt#L60)